# A lot of OutOfMemoryError from Samsung Galaxy devices on Android 7.x

Tags: android, crash, out-of-memory, crash-reports, google-play-console

I have an active app on Google Play Store. Since a few months I'm getting a lot of weird crash reports on Play Console.

Since I can't paste all the data here (there are A LOT of crash reports) I'm trying to show a good summary. Detailed info on request.

Mostly affected devices:

- Samsung Galaxy A5 2016 (a5xelte)
- Samsung Galaxy S5 (klte)
- Samsung Galaxy A5(2017) (a5y17lte)
- Samsung Galaxy Note3 (hlte)
- Samsung Galaxy S5 Neo (s5neolte)
- Samsung Galaxy S6 (zeroflte)

ND: The first device is very critical compared to the others

Types of crashes:

- `java.lang.RuntimeException` in `android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity`
- `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError` in `java.lang.StringFactory.newStringFromBytes`
- `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError` in `libcore.util.CharsetUtils.toUtf8Bytes`
- `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError` in `java.lang.StringFactory.newStringFromChars`
- `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError` in `java.lang.StringBuilder.toString`
- `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError` in `java.lang.StringFactory.newStringFromChars`

Android versions: 7.0, 7.1 and rarely 6.0

I don't know why this is happening on these devices, I don't know how to debug these reports and I didn't find anything similar on StackOverflow or any other sources. Any help?

---

**EDIT**, some stacktraces:

Samsung Galaxy A5(2016) (a5xelte), 2048MB RAM, Android 7.0

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2984)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3045)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14 (ActivityThread.java)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1642)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:154)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6776)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:1496)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1386)
```

Samsung Galaxy S6 Edge (zerolte), 3072MB RAM, Android 7.0

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: 
  at java.lang.StringFactory.newStringFromBytes (StringFactory.java:185)
  at java.lang.StringFactory.newStringFromBytes (StringFactory.java:63)
  at android.util.Base64.encodeToString (Base64.java:456)
  at org.chromium.android_webview.AwContents.loadDataWithBaseURL (AwContents.java:428)
  at com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewChromium.loadDataWithBaseURL (WebViewChromium.java:188)
  at android.webkit.WebView.loadDataWithBaseURL (WebView.java:1015)
  at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.webview.p.loadDataWithBaseURL (p.java:131)
  at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.webview.o.loadDataWithBaseURL (o.java:104)
  at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.renderer.i.a (i.java:8)
  at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.renderer.a.c (a.java:35)
  at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.renderer.g.a (g.java:11)
  at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.zzk.run (zzk.java:28)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:751)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:95)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:154)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6682)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:1520)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1410)
```

Samsung Galaxy A5(2016) (a5xelte), 2048MB RAM, Android 7.0

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: 
  at libcore.util.CharsetUtils.toUtf8Bytes (CharsetUtils.java)
  at java.lang.String.getBytes (String.java:879)
  at java.lang.String.getBytes (String.java:851)
  at org.chromium.android_webview.AwContents.loadDataWithBaseURL (AwContents.java:428)
  at com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewChromium.loadDataWithBaseURL (WebViewChromium.java:188)
  at android.webkit.WebView.loadDataWithBaseURL (WebView.java:1015)
  at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.webview.p.loadDataWithBaseURL (p.java:131)
  at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.webview.o.loadDataWithBaseURL (o.java:104)
  at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.renderer.i.a (i.java:8)
  at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.renderer.a.c (a.java:35)
  at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.renderer.g.a (g.java:11)
  at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.zzk.run (zzk.java:28)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:751)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:95)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:154)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6776)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:1496)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1386)
```

---

**EDIT 2**: I updated the dependencies of `firebase-ads` but I'm having still the same crashes. Plus, I had a new crash type in this version:

**Samsung Galaxy A5(2016) (a5xelte)**, 2048MB RAM, Android 7.0

```
java.lang.InternalError: 
  at java.lang.Thread.nativeCreate (Thread.java)
  at java.lang.Thread.start (Thread.java:731)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.addWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:941)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.processWorkerExit (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1009)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1151)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
  at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:762)
```

Comment: Please post actual complete stack traces, not just error messages.

Comment: Edited with some stack traces

Comment: The latter two are coming from Play Services' ad code. Make sure that you are on the latest version of their library.

Comment: Turns out I'm using an old version of com.google.firebase:firebase-ads. But how did you assume that? I need to know for future debugging

Comment: I am also having RuntimeExceptions on Android 7 and 7.1 . We are using firebase notifications in our project.

Comment: this bug was reported last year. Admob just assume that it is a problem with the user's implementation and closed the issue. :( https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-admob-ads-sdk/xtnAcmnPYFI

Comment: I have two questions for you two: 1) Does your app use a modest quantity of `ImageView`s? 2) do you have `largeHeap="true"` into your manifest?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I didn't want to resolve this way, but it *seems* to be solved by adding

```
largeHeap="true"
```

into my Manifest.

What did I figure out: Samsung Galaxy devices' memory are poorly optimized by Samsung (the Galaxy A5 2016 has 2GB of RAM. That's more than enough, but on Firebase I can see OOMs because of very little heap). So, I decided to settle things once and for all and I set largeHeap to true. I'm not proud of this choice but it seemed the only viable.

Result: all of OOMs *seems* to be gone, for now

Comment: Did this help with the first listed error? RuntimeException in  android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2984)   (Samsung Galaxy A5)

Comment: @OferR you should post the full stack trace

Comment: My question is whether this solution helped you with the problem *you* had, as listed in *your* question. The very first stack trace you listed. Have these errors disappeared after applying the largeHeap="true"?
(The problem you listed and I refer to is the first one. It shows RuntimeException in android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity  where the rest of your stack traces show OutOfMemoryError) ...  Thanks...

Comment: @OferR yes, to me it really helped. But it could be another thing, since RuntimeException is not necessarily thrown because small heap. If you are experiencing a lot of similar stacktraces from Samsung devices you could try to set `largeHeap="true"` and probably it would fix. If you do, please come here again to let other users know if it helped.

Comment: Thanks. I will. I don't get as many such errors, but these are always Samsung devices (including S8) and always on performLaunchActivity.

Answer (score 4):

Let's look at the last stack trace, in segments:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: 
  at libcore.util.CharsetUtils.toUtf8Bytes (CharsetUtils.java)
  at java.lang.String.getBytes (String.java:879)
  at java.lang.String.getBytes (String.java:851)
```

So, the specific thing that blew up was converting a `String` to a `byte[]`. Either you are very short on heap space, or that's a rather big string.

```
  at org.chromium.android_webview.AwContents.loadDataWithBaseURL (AwContents.java:428)
  at com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewChromium.loadDataWithBaseURL (WebViewChromium.java:188)
  at android.webkit.WebView.loadDataWithBaseURL (WebView.java:1015)
```

So, here we see that the thing with the `String` is `WebView`, via `loadDataWithBaseURL()`. This suggests that something is calling `loadDataWithBaseURL()` with a rather big URL. A `data:` URL would be one possibility.

```
  at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.webview.p.loadDataWithBaseURL (p.java:131)
  at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.webview.o.loadDataWithBaseURL (o.java:104)
  at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.renderer.i.a (i.java:8)
  at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.renderer.a.c (a.java:35)
  at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.renderer.g.a (g.java:11)
  at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.zzk.run (zzk.java:28)
```

Here, we have six lines that all come from the same Java package. `com.google.android.gms` is the top-level package for much of Play Services, so `com.google.android.gms.ads` presumably is one of their ad libraries. I don't use much of Play Services, so I'm not expert on exactly what ad network brands they still have and which one(s) map to `com.google.android.gms.ads`.

So, check your ad network libraries and make sure that you are on the latest-and-greatest that you can support. With luck, this is a bug that they fixed in their library somewhere along the line.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me this. I was using an old version on both `firebase-core` and `firebase-ads`. I hope the latest release fixes all the troubles with galaxy devices (even that anonymous RuntimeException on performLaunchActivity). Fingers crossed :)

Comment: @AndroidGuy: For that first stack trace, if there's nothing more to it, there's nothing much that you can do about it.There are no identifying characteristics pointing to your code or a library. And, if that's all you are getting, consider using something else for obtaining your crash logs. Usually these stack traces have multiple stanzas (`RuntimeException` and a bunch of lines, followed by `Caused by` and another exception and bunch of lines). Your real problem there may be reported in a later stanza, but if you do not have that portion of the stack trace, you're out of luck.

Comment: That's the problem. But I have noticed that all crashes like the one in the first stack trace are coming from Galaxy devices on Android 7.0. This makes me think it's linked to the issue in the `firebase-ads` library or in `firebase-core` (they both had the same old version number). I issued an update with the two libraries up to date. If that will not work I've put `firebase-crash` to the dependencies, it will enable crash reporting to firebase console and I hope it will help me with more accurate stack traces.

Comment: Unfortunately it seems that nothing has been fixed with the last update. See the second edit in the main post.

Comment: @AndroidGuy: Without more details from your crash logs, it will be difficult to impossible to pinpoint the source of a crash like that.